# benchRun query with sort by date field

Tags: mongodb

I would like to use benchRun http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/JS+Benchmarking+Harness on a query like this:

```
.find().sort({ last_date : 1 }).limit(1,
```

Is there a way to specify such a query in the "ops" JSON array? I couldn't see anything in the benchRun.cc source code, so I just wanted to check. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to use it for sort. It is "planned but not scheduled" according to the issue [SERVER-5722](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5722).